# Why there are duplicate entities results with google cloud natural language api?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was trying to analyze a pile of news records to get the sentiment to one species, using the [entity sentimental analysis of google cloud natural language api](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-entity-sentiment). But I found that the results have many duplicate entities with the same entity name, but different salience, sentiment and magnitude scores.

For example, I tried to analyze the sentiment to Tibetan gazelles with 17 related news records. "TibetanGazelle" appeared 19 times in the text in total. I got four entities of "TibetanGazelle" with analyzeEntitySentiment method of google cloud natural language api:

```
> Entity name: "TibetanGazelle" 
> Salience: 0.0005185807822272182
> Sentiment score: 0.0 
> Sentiment magnitude: 0.5

> Entity name: "TibetanGazelle" 
> Salience: 5.040658652433194e-05
> Sentiment score: 0.0 
> Sentiment magnitude: 0.10000000149011612

> Entity name: "TibetanGazelle" 
> Salience: 2.071916969725862e-05
> Sentiment score: -0.20000000298023224 
> Sentiment magnitude: 0.4000000059604645

> Entity name: "TibetanGazelle" 
> Salience: 9.712235623737797e-06
> Sentiment score: -0.20000000298023224 
> Sentiment magnitude: 0.4000000059604645
```

My questions is:

1. Why they were not identified as the same entities?
2. And how should I merge them into one entity?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but I've noticed some patterns that might indicate why. If it's a proper noun entity then there will be one entry, but if not then there will be as many entries as there are sentences that mention the entity. My guess is that it's obvious that proper nouns refer to a unique distinct entity that the whole text refers to, while other nouns are simply analyzed within the context of each sentence they appear in. I'm not sure about the significance of multiple salience/sentiment scores because the [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/Entity) indicates that these scores are relevant for the context of the whole text. It's not entirely scientific but that would be my guess.